# Controls inside UpdatePanel inside templates

Tags: asp.net, templates, updatepanel, formview

I have an asp:FormView with InsertItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate in it. Both are almost identical in all but codebehind functions behavior. By identical I mean both templates have controls with the same IDs. Everything seemed to work just fine until I added UpdatePanels in those templates. 
Now it says:
"The type 'ASP.quotation_quote_aspx' already contains a definition for 'MeasurmentUnits'".

Here's a sample:

```
<asp:FormView ID="QuoteMaterialForm" runat="server" DataSourceID="QuoteMaterialDS" DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Edit" OnLoad="QuoteMaterialForm_Load" >
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MaterialUpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table class="form">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Measurment units
                                                </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="MeasurmentUnits" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                    onclick="needToConfirm = true;" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                                    RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MeasurementUnits") %>'>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Imperial</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Metric</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                     </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MaterialUpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table class="form">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Measurment units
                                                </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="MeasurmentUnits" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                    onclick="needToConfirm = true;" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                                    RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MeasurementUnits") %>'>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Imperial</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Metric</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                     </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:FormView>
```

If I remove UpdatePanels from Templates - no such errors occur.

Any possible advice, please? =(

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug [UpdatePanel breaks naming-containers (Compile-Time Bug) by Robert Haken MVP](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/417230/updatepanel-breaks-naming-containers-compile-time-bug)

Comment: That's problematic, since both templates hold lots of controls. If I change all of theirs IDs, I'll have to change tons of codebehind logic, too. Are there any other options? Without enveloping the insides of the templates into UpdatePanels everything works ok with same IDs.

Comment: If you meant something like this: 
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:Panel>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
</InsertItemTemplate>
...

then it's not working either. =(